# Format string output

Tags: python, string

With this python's code I may read all tickers in the tickers.txt file:

```
fh = open("tickers.txt") 
tickers_list = fh.read()
print(tickers_list)
```

The output that I obtain is this:

A2A.MI, AMP.MI, ATL.MI, AZM.MI, BGN.MI, BMED.MI, BAMI.MI,

Neverthless, I'd like to obtain as ouput a ticker string exactly formatted in this manner:

["A2A.MI", "AMP.MI", "ATL.MI", "AZM.MI", ...]

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you need to split the string - `tickers_list.split(",")`. If it is a csv file read this as a csv file -  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Just a note, if you ask a question and someone answers a satisfactory answer, please don't forget to accept the answer. It would be also great to go back to questions you asked previously and select answers for any of the answered questions, this will both help you, as well as the people who are helping. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output to look in that format you want, you would need to do the following:

```
tickers_list= "A2A.MI, AMP.MI, ATL.MI, AZM.MI, BGN.MI, BMED.MI, BAMI.MI"
print("["+"".join(['"' + s + '",' for s in tickers_list.split(",")])[:-1]+"]")
```

With the output:

```
["A2A.MI"," AMP.MI"," ATL.MI"," AZM.MI"," BGN.MI"," BMED.MI"," BAMI.MI"]
```

Code explanation:

```
['"' + s + '",' for s in tickers_list.split(",")]
```

Creates a list of strings that contain each individual value, with the brackets as well as the comma.

```
"".join(...)[:-1]
```

Joins the list of strings into one string, removing the last character which is the extra comma

```
"["+..+"]"
```

adds the closing brackets

Another alternative is to simple use:

```
print(tickers_list.split(","))
```

However, the output will be slightly different as in:

```
['A2A.MI', ' AMP.MI', ' ATL.MI', ' AZM.MI', ' BGN.MI', ' BMED.MI', ' BAMI.MI']
```

Having `'` instead of `"`

A solution for that however is this:

```
z = str(tickers_list.split(","))
z = z.replace("'",'"')
print(z)
```

Having the correct output, by replacing that character

Comment: Hi Zaid. Thanks for you reply. It works fine but now I need to remove blank space after each ' " '. Anything like this: ["A2A.MI","AMP.MI","ATL.MI","AZM.MI","BGN.MI","BMED.MI","BAMI.MI"]. Any idea?

Comment: @M4Biz `print("["+"".join(['"' + s.strip() + '",' for s in tickers_list.split(",")])[:-1]+"]")`

Answer (score 0):

you can to use Split function:

```
tickers_list = fh.read().split(',')
```

Comment: This will work, but the output (at least for me on my compiler) was `['A2A.MI', ' AMP.MI', ' ATL.MI', ' AZM.MI', ' BGN.MI', ' BMED.MI', ' BAMI.MI']` instead of `["A2A.MI"," AMP.MI"," ATL.MI"," AZM.MI"," BGN.MI"," BMED.MI"," BAMI.MI"]`. I am not sure if different language/compiler settings result with a different string pre-fix